# File download For Current Request

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I need to download the file as http response for the current http request.

Until now I used code as

```
System.Uri uri = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;   

HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
    Path.Combine(uri.ToString(), filename));

httpRequest.Method = "GET";

using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse())
{                 
     using (Stream responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
     {
         using (FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(
             Path.Combine(localFolder, filename), FileMode.Open))
         {                  
             int bytesRead;

             while ((bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
             {
                 totalBytesRead += bytesRead;    
                 localFileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
             }
         }
     }
}
```

But this code the request is only sending but not getting any responses...

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried `WebClient.DownloadFile()`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx ...might make things a little simpler if all you are trying to do is download a file.

Comment: no will try and then update you

Comment: the link u gave is we need to give full path to download the file but my job is to send a file as response to that request and download it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the file off disk then use the Response.OutputStream to write the file directly to the response. Make sure to set the correct content headers so the browser will know what is coming.

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(localFolder, filename));
int len = (int)file.Length, bytes;
Response.ContentType = "text/plain"; //Set the file type here
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename; 
context.Response.AppendHeader("content-length", len.ToString());
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

using(Stream stream = File.OpenRead(path)) {
    while (len > 0 && (bytes =
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
        len -= bytes;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply even if it is zip file we can follow these steps ah

Comment: it works well with website or web application ... but i need to create with c# library project .i am getting error as in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859606/sending-httpresponses-in-library-file-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but it looks like your making a web request, getting the response stream, then attempting to buffer it out to localFolder.  If so, FileMode.Open looks suspect ("should open an existing file..."?).  Maybe use FileMode.Create.

[MSDN ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx)

Also, does your web app needs to have write permissions to localFolder.